# How to define the pipe operator?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, assignment-operator, magrittr

I like the pipe (in [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) or [magrittr](/questions/tagged/magrittr) as mentioned in the comments) a lot but sometimes I run into errors which show me that I lack some understanding. In case of other functions or operators I mostly have at least some idea how they may be defined, but in case of the pipe I do not have even a clue where to start if I want to define it.

I am really curious how the pipe is defined. So far I simply tried to assign it to an own operator but even this does not work. See here:

```
library(dplyr)

`%pipe%` <- `%>%`

data.frame() %pipe% class(.)
# gives an error: subscript out of bounds
```

What magical ingredients make a pipe work? How could we define it ourselves? Thanks.

Comment: The pipe is actually not a dplyr function, dplyr imports it from a package called magrittr. you can find its definition in the documentation:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html

Comment: @dvd I made an edit. By definition I mean the code. Where can I find it?

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/tree/master/R

Comment: @dvd Wow, that is impressive and there are even many functions inside that must be defined, too. Thanks. I copy&pasted all the stuff and it actually works. But I am afraid I will not get all of that :D At least not for a while..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

magrittr's code itself checks if the pipe you used is named as one of the few allowed names, as seen at the top here: https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/blob/master/R/is_something.R .

In fact all pipes have the same code, copied from `magrittr:::pipe` as seen as the bottom of this script :

https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/blob/master/R/pipe.R

The behavior depends on the name of the pipe, it's really odd and I've never seen this anywhere else.

I'll try to make it less confusing by inventing a fake function behaving likewise, forgive the silliness of the example.

```r
concat <- function(x,y) {
  # extract quoted function name from call
  fun <- sys.call()[[1]]

  # check if it's one of our possible names, and act accordingly
  if(identical(fun, quote(`%upconcat>%`))) {
    return(toupper(paste0(x,y)))
  } 
  if(identical(fun, quote(`%lowconcat>%`))) {
    return(tolower(paste0(x,y)))
  } 
  stop("Unsupported operator!")
}
`%upconcat>%` <- `%lowconcat>%` <- concat

"XoX" %upconcat>% "oXo"
#> [1] "XOXOXO"
"XoX" %lowconcat>% "oXo"
#> [1] "xoxoxo"

`%foo>%` <- `%upconcat>%`
"XoX" %foo>% "oXo"
#> Error in "XoX" %foo>% "oXo": Unsupported operator!
```

You see there's no way to copy the pipe unless you modify the `is_pipe` function itself, which you can't do...

Just kidding, of course you can, but probably you shouldn't ?

```r
library(magrittr)
is_pipe <- function(pipe) {
  identical(pipe, quote(`%>%`))   ||
    identical(pipe, quote(`%T>%`))  ||
    identical(pipe, quote(`%<>%`))  ||
    identical(pipe, quote(`%$%`)) ||
    identical(pipe, quote(`%pipe%`)) # <- added line
}

assignInNamespace("is_pipe", is_pipe, "magrittr")
`%pipe%` <- `%>%`

data.frame() %pipe% class(.)
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! `magrittr:::pipe` is apparently the answer to the question how the pipe is defined. What I dont undetstand: I assigned the code that is shown in `magrittr:::` to `%>%` which in my understanding should make the pipe but it does not work. What I did is: `\`%>%\` <- function () {
    function(lhs, rhs) {
        parent <- parent.frame()
        env <- new.env(parent = parent)
        chain_parts <- split_chain(match.call(), env = env)...`

Comment: Because split_chains among others is not exported, your new pipe can't access it anymore because you defined it in the global env. This is not specific to magrittr